# Filtering / moving average of 3D gridded climate array

Tags: matlab, filter, 3d

I have a 3D gridded array of size n x m x p, where n = lat, m = lon and p = 30 min time intervals.

I need to remove the tidal signal by filtering / averaging to 25 hours.

I can do daily averages using the function downsample_ts, but it doesnt allow custom time inputs.

I also tried movmean but I can t get it to work on a 3D array.

Comment: `movmean` works fine on a 3D matrix. You want to average 25 hours, so you need an averaging window of 50 points (50x30mn=25hours). You need to average on the 3rd dimension of your matrix, so it becomes: `M = movmean( A , 50 , 3)`. The new matrix `B` will be averaged over time, but it will not be downsampled, it will still contains the same number of points.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will downsample after applying the moving average